# mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, composer

Cuando ejecuto `composer create-project laravel/laravel nombre_proyecto`, este me ocasiona el error de:

> mkdir(): Permission denied

Foto:

[image: la]

Todo esto en `ubuntu 18.04 LTS`.

**EDICION**
al ejecutar: `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html`

El siguiente error vuelve a saltar:

> chmod: cambiando los permisos de '/var/www/html': Operación no permitida
>   chmod: cambiando los permisos de '/var/www/html/index.html': Operación no permitida

Al ejecutar `ls -l /var/www`

Me muestra:

> total 4
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 may  9 00:12 html

Como soluciono esto?

Comment: probaste con sudo?

Comment: @x-rw Antes de composer?? perdon es que apenas e inicio con ubuntu

Comment: sudo  composer create-project laravel/laravel nombre_proyecto y luego pones tu contraseña

Comment: @x-rw, ya lo hice ahora me muestra : `Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details`. y segun mi ingles esto no funcionara.

Comment: entonces cambia los permisos a tu carpeta con chmod -R 777 ./nombre_carpeta

Comment: ¿Eso es en un servidor o es un entorno local? ¿ podrías hacer un `ls -l /var/www` para ver los permisos que tiene el directorio `/var/www/html`? Te aparecerá en la primer columna los permisos, y en la tercera el usuario y grupo al que pertenecen.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, edite mi pregunta con los resultados ahora que debo de hacer?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, ubuntu instalador en mi pc tendria que ser local. estoy algo perdido en esto de servidores es por eso que estoy iniciándome, siempre he trabajado con windows.

Comment: Tenía el mismo problema y me sirvió la respuesta de @userStack al asignarle los permisos a la carpeta de htdocs (utilizo Xampp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al ejecutar `ls -l /var/www`

Muestra:

```
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 may 9 00:12 html
```

De ahí lo que nos interesa son:

- La *primer columna*, que te indica que tipo de archivo es y los
  permisos que tiene asignados.
- La *tercer columna*, que te muestra el usuario y el grupo al que
  pertenece.
- Y la última, que es el nombre, ya que donde quieres instalar laravel
  es en el directorio `html`.

De esa *primer columna*, esto `drwxr-xr-x` quiere decir:

- La `d` del inicio indica que es un directorio.
- Los siguientes `rwx` son los permisos que tiene el **usuario dueño** del
  directoro, `r` = read (leer), `w` = write (escribir) y `x` = execute
  (ejecutar).
- Los siguientes `r-x` son los permisos que tiene el **grupo** de usuarios
  al que pertenece el directorio.
- Y los últimos `r-x` son los permisos que tiene el resto del mundo.

El tema ahí, es que ese directorio pertenece al superusuario `root`, como puedes ver en la *tercer columna* del listado `root root`, donde el primer `root` se refiere al **usuario dueño**, y el segundo `root` al **grupo dueño** de ese directorio.

Lo más simple ahí, sería cambiar el **usuario dueño**, para que ese directorio pertenezca a tu usuario (`shassain` por lo que se puede ver en la captura), con lo que lograrás los permisos `rwx` que ya tiene asignados el directorio para su **usuario dueño**. Puedes cambiar el dueño del directorio con el comando:

```
sudo chown shassain /var/www/html
```

Y al ejecutar otra vez `ls -l /var/www`

Deberías ver algo así:

```
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 shassain root 4096 may 9 00:12 html
```

Y ya estarías en condiciones de escribir en ese directorio `html`, pues a los que se refiere el error es a que tu usuario `shassain` no tenía permiso de escritura ahí.

Comment: Esto me ha funcionado, aunque de rato en rato al instalar el proyecto me salia `Cannot create cache directory /home/shassain/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache`, pero el proyecto se creo correctamente, ademas de que ese ya es otro tema. mil gracias.

Comment: Ok, eso es porque composer intenta guardar un cache de los paquetes que descarga, para no tener que descargarlos de nuevo cada vez que quieras instalar los mismos paquetes, por ejemplo cuando quieras instalar otro proyecto laravel. Puedes cambiar el dueño de ese directorio de la misma manera `sudo chown -R shassain /home/shassain/.composer/cache/files/`. Sólo ten en cuenta agregar ese `-R` para que el cambio sea recursivo a todos los subdirectorio y archivos ahí.

Comment: Gracias por la info.

Answer (score 1):

intenta con

```
sudo su composer create-project laravel/laravel nombre_proyecto
```

Comment: "Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details" o en español "¡No ejecute Composer como usuario root/superusuario! Consulte https://getcomposer.org/root para más detalles."

Comment: Este comando me lanza el error que indica porloscerros.