# php artisan storage:link = symlink(): Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, ssh, permisos

Tengo un proyecto de Laravel 8 en un hosting compartido.
Al intentar ejecutar el comando por ssh `php artisan storage:link` para mostrar las imágenes, me muestra un error.

```
ErrorException

  symlink(): Permission denied

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:315
    311▕      */
    312▕     public function link($target, $link)
    313▕     {
    314▕         if (! windows_os()) {
  ➜ 315▕             return symlink($target, $link);
    316▕         }
    317▕
    318▕         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    319▕

      +15 vendor frames
  16  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Intente cambiar los permisos del artivo `Filesystem.php` asi como de todos los directorios arriba de el, pero el problema persiste.

Realmente no se a que debo de cambiar los permisos.

Comment: Parece que el usuario con el que ejecutas el comando no tiene permiso de escribir en el directorio public/, o de leer en storage/. Que te devuelve si hace `ls -l` en la terminal?

Comment: Al ejecutar el comando que me indicas en la raiz del proyecto, me muestra esto en el directorio storage: drwxrwxrwx   5 u819425214 o52166886      4096 Mar 26 00:56 storage . Soy nuevo en esto y aun desconozco lo que significa las iniciales de los permisos.

Comment: ¿Y en el directorio `public/`? También sería útil saber con qué usuario estás ejecutando el comando. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354018/mkdir-permission-denied/354036#354036) tienes una respuesta donde se explica un poco cómo leer los permisos de archivos y directorios en linux, por si quieres enterarte.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes acceso a SSH de tu hosting? si es asi, dale permisos a la carpeta storage del proyecto, asi:

```
chmod 777 -R
```

Comment: Por qué 777? Y más específicamente el último 7?

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y el problema persiste, ¿algún otra idea?

Answer (score 0):

**No edites los permisos a 777**, ya que crearás una vulnerabilidad de seguridad bastante importante.
La recomendación es  para los **directorios 755** y para los **ficheros 644** de todo el proyecto.

**Si estas trabajando sobre linux**, te recomiendo que incluyas al usuario que ejecuta php dentro de un grupo con permisos sobre la carpeta del proyecto. Para saber qué usuario es el ejecutor: `echo exec('whoami');`. Te dejo un link donde se explica bastante bien el tema de usuarios, grupos y permisos en linux: [gestión de usuarios y permisos en linux](https://computernewage.com/2016/05/22/gestionar-usuarios-y-permisos-en-linux/)

**En el caso de que estés trabajando con xampp** (que no creo por lo que comentas pero por si acaso te lo comento a ver si ayuda), para solucionar tu problema **ejecuta el xampp como administrador**:
Para ejecutar el panel de control como administrador, se puede hacer clic derecho sobre el icono de acceso directo (Inicio > XAMPP > XAMPP Control Panel) y elegir la opción "Más > Ejecutar como administrador". Te dejo un link donde se explica mejor: [Ejecutar xampp como administrador](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/otros/xampp-instalacion-windows.html#:%7E:text=Para%20ejecutar%20el%20panel%20de,M%C3%A1s%20%3E%20Ejecutar%20como%20administrador%22.)